# Sql query related to 1st and 2nd highest salary

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can somebody tell me how this sql query evaluates :

```
SELECT e.sal 
FROM employees e 
WHERE 1 >= (
    SELECT count(*) 
    FROM employess s 
    WHERE s.sal>e.sal
)
```

I know this query returns 1st and 2nd highest salary.  But I want to understand the working of this query.  I want to know how it returns 1st and 2nd highest salary.  Please explain in detail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can somebody explain how the following SQL query to get the 'n' highest salary works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502258/can-somebody-explain-how-the-following-sql-query-to-get-the-n-highest-salary-w)

Answer (score 4):

The subselect

```
 (SELECT count(*) FROM employess s WHERE s.sal>e.sal)
```

returns number of employees with salary greater than the current employee you looking at in the top level `select`.

So the query basically says *give me all employees such that have 1 or less other employees earn more than them*

Pretty straight forward though horribly inefficient. The easier way would be simply this:

```
select top 2 * from employees order by sal desc
```

**EDIT:** This will return top 2 employees with highest salary, which as Gordon noted is not the same as top 2 distinct salary values, since people may have exactly the same salary.
If that is a concern that you'd have to dedupe it first like this:

```
select top 2 sal from employees group by sal order by sal desc
```

Comment: Agreed -- +1 for explanation of query which was the question.

Comment: This answer (and the question) miss the situation where multiple employees have the highest salary.  In this case, more than two rows can be returned, and the query is *not* equivalent to the version with `top`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff updated my answer to address duplicate salary values

Answer (score 1):

To get your 1st and 2nd highest salary, I'd use `ROW_NUMBER()`.  That should make it easy to understand the rankings of the salaries.  Or if you need to account for ties, look into using `RANK()`.

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT sal, Row 
FROM (
   SELECT sal, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY sal DESC) AS Row
   FROM employees e ) t
WHERE Row IN (1,2);
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6c9cd/7).

Good luck.

Comment: Something to note..SQL Server seems to produce a more expensive plan with the `WHERE Row IN (1,2)` filter than with just doing a `SELECT TOP(2)`

Comment: Good comment, but in this case, we're safe.  Here is a list of all reserved keywords in SQL Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT: I missed the e and the s. So my answer is incorrect.

That query should return everything.

```
(SELECT count(*) FROM employess s WHERE s.sal>e.sal)
```

Since e.sal will NEVER be > e.sal (1 can never be > 1), thus, the count(*) will always be 0.
and `SELECT e.sal FROM employees e WHERE 1 >= (0)`  will always be everything

If you want to return the top 2 salary, you might want to try this:

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM employess AS e ORDER BY e.sal DESC
```

Comment: "Since e.sal will NEVER be >" huh? why?